# Find the nth occurrence of substring in a string

Tags: python, string, substring

This seems like it should be pretty trivial, but I am new at Python and want to do it the most Pythonic way.

I want to find the index corresponding to the n'th occurrence of a substring within a string.

There's got to be something equivalent to what I WANT to do which is

`mystring.find("substring", 2nd)`

How can you achieve this in Python?

Comment: Find the n'th occurence of the string? I assume it means the index of the n'th occurence?

Comment: Yes, the index of the n'th occurence

Comment: What should happen if there are overlapping matches? Should find_nth('aaaa', 'aa', 2) return 1 or 2?

Comment: Yes! there's got to be something to find the n'th occurrence of a substring in a string and to split the string at the n'th occurrence of a substring.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Mark's iterative approach would be the usual way, I think.

Here's an alternative with string-splitting, which can often be useful for finding-related processes:

```
def findnth(haystack, needle, n):
    parts= haystack.split(needle, n+1)
    if len(parts)<=n+1:
        return -1
    return len(haystack)-len(parts[-1])-len(needle)
```

And here's a quick (and somewhat dirty, in that you have to choose some chaff that can't match the needle) one-liner:

```
'foo bar bar bar'.replace('bar', 'XXX', 1).find('bar')
```

Comment: The first suggestion is going to be very inefficient for large strings when the match you're interested is near the beginning. It always looks at the whole string. It's clever but I wouldn't recommend this to someone who is new to Python and just wants to learn a good way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, I like your one liner. I don't think it's the most instantly readable thing in the world, but it's not much worse then most others below

Comment: +1 for the one-liner, this should help me right now.  I had been thinking of doing the equivalent of `.rfind('XXX')`, but that would fall apart if `'XXX'` appears later in the input anyway.

Comment: This function assume n = 0, 1, 2, 3, ... It would be nice you assume n = 1, 2, 3, 4, ...

Answer (score 128):

Here's a more Pythonic version of the straightforward iterative solution:

```
def find_nth(haystack: str, needle: str, n: int) -> int:
    start = haystack.find(needle)
    while start >= 0 and n > 1:
        start = haystack.find(needle, start+len(needle))
        n -= 1
    return start
```

*Example:*

```
>>> find_nth("foofoofoofoo", "foofoo", 2)
6
```

If you want to find the nth *overlapping* occurrence of `needle`, you can increment by `1` instead of `len(needle)`, like this:

```
def find_nth_overlapping(haystack, needle, n):
    start = haystack.find(needle)
    while start >= 0 and n > 1:
        start = haystack.find(needle, start+1)
        n -= 1
    return start
```

*Example:*

```
>>> find_nth_overlapping("foofoofoofoo", "foofoo", 2)
3
```

This is easier to read than Mark's version, and it doesn't require the extra memory of the splitting version or importing regular expression module.  It also adheres to a few of the rules in the [Zen of python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), unlike the various `re` approaches:

1. Simple is better than complex.
2. Flat is better than nested.
3. Readability counts.

Comment: Can this be done in a string?  Like find_nth(df.mystring.str, ('x'), 2) to find the position of the 2nd instance of 'x'?

Comment: Suggested doc string for `find_nth`: `"""Finds index of the *n*'th occurrence of *needle* within *haystack*.
    Returns -1 when the *n*'th occurrence is not found."""`

Comment: find_nth can be extended to support a starting position within haystack by adding a fourth arg 'start_position=0' and then modifying the first line to read `start = haystack.find(needle, start_position)`

Answer (score 52):

This will find the second occurrence of substring in string.

```
def find_2nd(string, substring):
   return string.find(substring, string.find(substring) + 1)
```

Edit: I haven't thought much about the performance, but a quick recursion can help with finding the nth occurrence:

```
def find_nth(string, substring, n):
   if (n == 1):
       return string.find(substring)
   else:
       return string.find(substring, find_nth(string, substring, n - 1) + 1)
```

Comment: Can this be extended generally to find the n-th element?

Comment: This the best answer IMHO, I made a small addition for the special case where n=0

Comment: I didn't want to edit the post for brevity. I agree with you though, that n=0 should be treated as a special case.

Comment: This should be adjusted to handle for the case where there are fewer than `n` occurences of the substring. (In this case the return value will cycle periodically through all the occurence positions).

Answer (score 38):

Understanding that regex is not always the best solution, I'd probably use one here:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "ababdfegtduab"
>>> [m.start() for m in re.finditer(r"ab",s)]
[0, 2, 11]
>>> [m.start() for m in re.finditer(r"ab",s)][2] #index 2 is third occurrence 
11
```

Comment: The risk here of course is that the string to search for will contain special characters that will cause the regex to do something you didn't want. Using re.escape should solve this.

Comment: This is clever, but is it really Pythonic? Seems like overkill for just finding the nth occurrence of a substring, and it's not exactly easy to read.  Also, like you say, you have to import all of re for this

Comment: When you use square brackets, you tell Python to create the whole list. Round brackets would iterate only through the first elements, which is more effective: `(m.start() for m in re.finditer(r"ab",s))[2]`

Comment: @emu No, what you've posted won't work; you can't take an index of a generator.

Comment: @MarkAmery sorry! I'm quite surprised why I posted that code. Still, a similar and ugly solution is possible using the `itertools.islice` function: `next(islice(re.finditer(r"ab",s), 2, 2+1)).start()`

Answer (score 21):

I'm offering some benchmarking results comparing the most prominent approaches presented so far, namely @bobince's `findnth()` (based on `str.split()`) vs. @tgamblin's or @Mark Byers' `find_nth()` (based on `str.find()`). I will also compare with a C extension (`_find_nth.so`) to see how fast we can go. Here is `find_nth.py`:

```
def findnth(haystack, needle, n):
    parts= haystack.split(needle, n+1)
    if len(parts)<=n+1:
        return -1
    return len(haystack)-len(parts[-1])-len(needle)

def find_nth(s, x, n=0, overlap=False):
    l = 1 if overlap else len(x)
    i = -l
    for c in xrange(n + 1):
        i = s.find(x, i + l)
        if i < 0:
            break
    return i
```

Of course, performance matters most if the string is large, so suppose we want to find the 1000001st newline ('\n') in a 1.3 GB file called 'bigfile'. To save memory, we would like to work on an `mmap.mmap` object representation of the file:

```
In [1]: import _find_nth, find_nth, mmap

In [2]: f = open('bigfile', 'r')

In [3]: mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
```

There is already the first problem with `findnth()`, since `mmap.mmap` objects don't support `split()`. So we actually have to copy the whole file into memory:

```
In [4]: %time s = mm[:]
CPU times: user 813 ms, sys: 3.25 s, total: 4.06 s
Wall time: 17.7 s
```

Ouch! Fortunately `s` still fits in the 4 GB of memory of my Macbook Air, so let's benchmark `findnth()`:

```
In [5]: %timeit find_nth.findnth(s, '\n', 1000000)
1 loops, best of 3: 29.9 s per loop
```

Clearly a terrible performance. Let's see how the approach based on `str.find()` does:

```
In [6]: %timeit find_nth.find_nth(s, '\n', 1000000)
1 loops, best of 3: 774 ms per loop
```

Much better! Clearly, `findnth()`'s problem is that it is forced to copy the string during `split()`, which is already the second time we copied the 1.3 GB of data around after `s = mm[:]`. Here comes in the second advantage of `find_nth()`: We can use it on `mm` directly, such that *zero* copies of the file are required:

```
In [7]: %timeit find_nth.find_nth(mm, '\n', 1000000)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.21 s per loop
```

There appears to be a small performance penalty operating on `mm` vs. `s`, but this illustrates that `find_nth()` can get us an answer in 1.2 s compared to `findnth`'s total of 47 s.

I found no cases where the `str.find()` based approach was significantly worse than the `str.split()` based approach, so at this point, I would argue that @tgamblin's or @Mark Byers' answer should be accepted instead of @bobince's.

In my testing, the version of `find_nth()` above was the fastest pure Python solution I could come up with (very similar to @Mark Byers' version). Let's see how much better we can do with a C extension module. Here is `_find_nthmodule.c`:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <string.h>

off_t _find_nth(const char *buf, size_t l, char c, int n) {
    off_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
        if (buf[i] == c && n-- == 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

off_t _find_nth2(const char *buf, size_t l, char c, int n) {
    const char *b = buf - 1;
    do {
        b = memchr(b + 1, c, l);
        if (!b) return -1;
    } while (n--);
    return b - buf;
}

/* mmap_object is private in mmapmodule.c - replicate beginning here */
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    char *data;
    size_t size;
} mmap_object;

typedef struct {
    const char *s;
    size_t l;
    char c;
    int n;
} params;

int parse_args(PyObject *args, params *P) {
    PyObject *obj;
    const char *x;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "Osi", &obj, &x, &P->n)) {
        return 1;
    }
    PyTypeObject *type = Py_TYPE(obj);

    if (type == &PyString_Type) {
        P->s = PyString_AS_STRING(obj);
        P->l = PyString_GET_SIZE(obj);
    } else if (!strcmp(type->tp_name, "mmap.mmap")) {
        mmap_object *m_obj = (mmap_object*) obj;
        P->s = m_obj->data;
        P->l = m_obj->size;
    } else {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "Cannot obtain char * from argument 0");
        return 1;
    }
    P->c = x[0];
    return 0;
}

static PyObject* py_find_nth(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    params P;
    if (!parse_args(args, &P)) {
        return Py_BuildValue("i", _find_nth(P.s, P.l, P.c, P.n));
    } else {
        return NULL;    
    }
}

static PyObject* py_find_nth2(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    params P;
    if (!parse_args(args, &P)) {
        return Py_BuildValue("i", _find_nth2(P.s, P.l, P.c, P.n));
    } else {
        return NULL;    
    }
}

static PyMethodDef methods[] = {
    {"find_nth", py_find_nth, METH_VARARGS, ""},
    {"find_nth2", py_find_nth2, METH_VARARGS, ""},
    {0}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC init_find_nth(void) {
    Py_InitModule("_find_nth", methods);
}
```

Here is the `setup.py` file:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
module = Extension('_find_nth', sources=['_find_nthmodule.c'])
setup(ext_modules=[module])
```

Install as usual with `python setup.py install`. The C code plays at an advantage here since it is limited to finding single characters, but let's see how fast this is:

```
In [8]: %timeit _find_nth.find_nth(mm, '\n', 1000000)
1 loops, best of 3: 218 ms per loop

In [9]: %timeit _find_nth.find_nth(s, '\n', 1000000)
1 loops, best of 3: 216 ms per loop

In [10]: %timeit _find_nth.find_nth2(mm, '\n', 1000000)
1 loops, best of 3: 307 ms per loop

In [11]: %timeit _find_nth.find_nth2(s, '\n', 1000000)
1 loops, best of 3: 304 ms per loop
```

Clearly quite a bit faster still. Interestingly, there is no difference on the C level between the in-memory and mmapped cases. It is also interesting to see that `_find_nth2()`, which is based on `string.h`'s `memchr()` library function, loses out against the straightforward implementation in `_find_nth()`: The additional "optimizations" in `memchr()` are apparently backfiring...

In conclusion, the implementation in `findnth()` (based on `str.split()`) is really a bad idea, since (a) it performs terribly for larger strings due to the required copying, and (b) 
it doesn't work on `mmap.mmap` objects at all. The implementation in `find_nth()` (based on `str.find()`) should be preferred in all circumstances (and therefore be the accepted answer to this question).

There is still quite a bit of room for improvement, since the C extension ran almost a factor of 4 faster than the pure Python code, indicating that there might be a case for a dedicated Python library function.

Answer (score 18):

Simplest way?

```
text = "This is a test from a test ok" 

firstTest = text.find('test')

print text.find('test', firstTest + 1)
```

Comment: I can imagine that this is quite performant as well, compared to other solutions.

Comment: that's the most easiest approach, I like it

Answer (score 9):

I'd probably do something like this, using the find function that takes an index parameter:

```
def find_nth(s, x, n):
    i = -1
    for _ in range(n):
        i = s.find(x, i + len(x))
        if i == -1:
            break
    return i

print find_nth('bananabanana', 'an', 3)
```

It's not particularly Pythonic I guess, but it's simple. You could do it using recursion instead:

```
def find_nth(s, x, n, i = 0):
    i = s.find(x, i)
    if n == 1 or i == -1:
        return i 
    else:
        return find_nth(s, x, n - 1, i + len(x))

print find_nth('bananabanana', 'an', 3)
```

It's a functional way to solve it, but I don't know if that makes it more Pythonic.

Comment: `for _ in xrange(n):` can be used instead of `while n: ... n-=1`

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: Yeah, I guess that's a little more Pythonic. I'll update.

Comment: BTW: xrange is no longer needed in Python 3: http://diveintopython3.org/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html#xrange

Comment: `return find_nth(s, x, n - 1, i + 1)` should be `return find_nth(s, x, n - 1, i + len(x))`. Not a big deal, but saves some computation time.

Comment: @dlo: Actually that can give different results in some cases: find_nth('aaaa','aa',2). Mine gives 1, yours gives 2. I guess yours is actually what the poster wants. I'll update my code. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: `print find_nth('bananabanana', 'ban', 1)` prints 6 instead of 0 for the iterative solution, recursive works correctly. To fix, add `if n == 0: return -1; i = -len(x)` to beginning.

Answer (score 6):

This will give you an array of the starting indices for matches to `yourstring`:

```
import re
indices = [s.start() for s in re.finditer(':', yourstring)]
```

Then your nth entry would be:

```
n = 2
nth_entry = indices[n-1]
```

Of course you have to be careful with the index bounds. You can get the number of instances of `yourstring` like this:

```
num_instances = len(indices)
```

Answer (score 3):

For the special case where you search for the n'th occurence of a character (i.e. substring of length 1), the following function works by building a list of all positions of occurences of the given character:

```
def find_char_nth(string, char, n):
    """Find the n'th occurence of a character within a string."""
    return [i for i, c in enumerate(string) if c == char][n-1]
```

If there are fewer than `n` occurences of the given character, it will give `IndexError: list index out of range`.

This is derived from @Zv_oDD's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43301645/650222) and simplified for the case of a single character.

Comment: This is beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach using re.finditer.
The difference is that this only looks into the haystack as far as necessary

```
from re import finditer
from itertools import dropwhile
needle='an'
haystack='bananabanana'
n=2
next(dropwhile(lambda x: x[0]<n, enumerate(re.finditer(needle,haystack))))[1].start()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another `re` + `itertools` version that should work when searching for either a `str` or a `RegexpObject`. I will freely admit that this is likely over-engineered, but for some reason it entertained me.

```
import itertools
import re

def find_nth(haystack, needle, n = 1):
    """
    Find the starting index of the nth occurrence of ``needle`` in \
    ``haystack``.

    If ``needle`` is a ``str``, this will perform an exact substring
    match; if it is a ``RegexpObject``, this will perform a regex
    search.

    If ``needle`` doesn't appear in ``haystack``, return ``-1``. If
    ``needle`` doesn't appear in ``haystack`` ``n`` times,
    return ``-1``.

    Arguments
    ---------
    * ``needle`` the substring (or a ``RegexpObject``) to find
    * ``haystack`` is a ``str``
    * an ``int`` indicating which occurrence to find; defaults to ``1``

    >>> find_nth("foo", "o", 1)
    1
    >>> find_nth("foo", "o", 2)
    2
    >>> find_nth("foo", "o", 3)
    -1
    >>> find_nth("foo", "b")
    -1
    >>> import re
    >>> either_o = re.compile("[oO]")
    >>> find_nth("foo", either_o, 1)
    1
    >>> find_nth("FOO", either_o, 1)
    1
    """
    if (hasattr(needle, 'finditer')):
        matches = needle.finditer(haystack)
    else:
        matches = re.finditer(re.escape(needle), haystack)
    start_here = itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x[0] < n, enumerate(matches, 1))
    try:
        return next(start_here)[1].start()
    except StopIteration:
        return -1
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on **modle13**'s answer, but without the `re` module dependency.

```
def iter_find(haystack, needle):
    return [i for i in range(0, len(haystack)) if haystack[i:].startswith(needle)]
```

I kinda wish this was a builtin string method.

```
>>> iter_find("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883980/", '/')
[5, 6, 24, 34, 42]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s="abcdefabcdefababcdef"
>>> j=0
>>> for n,i in enumerate(s):
...   if s[n:n+2] =="ab":
...     print n,i
...     j=j+1
...     if j==2: print "2nd occurence at index position: ",n
...
0 a
6 a
2nd occurence at index position:  6
12 a
14 a
```

Answer (score 1):

Providing another "tricky" solution, which use `split` and `join`.

In your example, we can use

```
len("substring".join([s for s in ori.split("substring")[:2]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# return -1 if nth substr (0-indexed) d.n.e, else return index
def find_nth(s, substr, n):
    i = 0
    while n >= 0:
        n -= 1
        i = s.find(substr, i + 1)
    return i
```

Comment: needs an explanation

Comment: `find_nth('aaa', 'a', 0)` returns `1` while it should return `0`. You need something like `i = s.find(substr, i) + 1` and then return `i - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution without using loops and recursion.

> Use the required pattern in compile method and enter the desired
>   occurrence in variable **'n'** and the last statement will print the
>   starting index of the nth occurrence of the pattern in the given
>   string. Here the result of finditer i.e. iterator is being converted
>   to list and directly accessing the nth index.

```
import re
n=2
sampleString="this is history"
pattern=re.compile("is")
matches=pattern.finditer(sampleString)
print(list(matches)[n].span()[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for finding `n`th occurrance of `b` in string `a`:

```py
from functools import reduce


def findNth(a, b, n):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: -1 if y > x + 1 else a.find(b, x + 1), range(n), -1)
```

It is pure Python and iterative. For 0 or `n` that is too large, it returns -1. It is one-liner and can be used directly. Here is an example:

```sh
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: -1 if y > x + 1 else 'bibarbobaobaotang'.find('b', x + 1), range(4), -1)
7
```

Answer (score 1):

I used findnth() function and ran into some issues, so I rewrote a faster version of the function (no list splitting):

```
def findnth(haystack, needle, n):
    if not needle in haystack or haystack.count(needle) < n:
        return -1

    last_index = 0
    cumulative_last_index = 0
    for i in range(0, n):
        last_index = haystack[cumulative_last_index:].find(needle)
        cumulative_last_index += last_index
        
        # if not last element, then jump over it
        if i < n-1:
            cumulative_last_index += len(needle)

    return cumulative_last_index
```

Answer (score 0):

The replace one liner is great but only works because XX and bar have the same lentgh

A good and general def would be:

```
def findN(s,sub,N,replaceString="XXX"):
    return s.replace(sub,replaceString,N-1).find(sub) - (len(replaceString)-len(sub))*(N-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Def:

```
def get_first_N_words(mytext, mylen = 3):
    mylist = list(mytext.split())
    if len(mylist)>=mylen: return ' '.join(mylist[:mylen])
```

To use:

```
get_first_N_words('  One Two Three Four ' , 3)
```

Output:

```
'One Two Three'
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid a failure or incorrect output when the input value for occurrence provided is higher than the actual count of occurrence. For example, in a string 'overflow' if you would check the 3rd occurrence of 'o' ( it has only 2 occurrences ) then below code will return a warning or message indicating that the occurrence value has exceeded.

### Input Occurrence entered has exceeded the actual count of Occurrence.

```
def check_nth_occurrence (string, substr, n):

## Count the Occurrence of a substr
    cnt = 0
    for i in string:
        if i ==substr:
            cnt = cnt + 1
        else:
            pass

## Check if the Occurrence input has exceeded the actual count of Occurrence

    if n > cnt:
        print (f' Input Occurrence entered has exceeded the actual count of Occurrence')
        return

## Get the Index value for first Occurrence of the substr

   index = string.find(substr)

## Get the Index value for nth Occurrence of Index
    while index >= 0 and n > 1:
        index = string.find(substr, index+ 1)
        n -= 1
  return index
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple and fun way to do it:

```
def index_of_nth(text, substring, n) -> int:
    index = 0
    for _ in range(n):
        index = text.index(substring, index) + 1
    return index - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in-case anyone wants to find n-th from the back:

```
def find_nth_reverse(haystack: str, needle: str, n: int) -> int:
    end = haystack.rfind(needle)

    while end >= 0 and n > 1:
        end = haystack.rfind(needle, 0, end - len(needle))
        n -= 1

    return end
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this.

```
def second_index(text: str, symbol: str) -> [int, None]:
"""
    returns the second index of a symbol in a given text
"""
first = text.find(symbol)
result = text.find(symbol,first+1)
if result > 0: return result
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the answer you really want:

```
def Find(String,ToFind,Occurence = 1):
index = 0 
count = 0
while index <= len(String):
    try:
        if String[index:index + len(ToFind)] == ToFind:
            count += 1
        if count == Occurence:
               return index
               break
        index += 1
    except IndexError:
        return False
        break
return False
```

Answer (score -2):

A simple solution for those with basic programming knowledge:

```
# Function to find the nth occurrence of a substring in a text
def findnth(text, substring, n):

# variable to store current index in loop
count = -1

# n count
occurance = 0

# loop through string
for letter in text:
    
    # increment count
    count += 1
    
    # if current letter in loop matches substring target
    if letter == substring:
        
        # increment occurance
        occurance += 1
        
        # if this is the nth time the substring is found
        if occurance == n:
            
            # return its index
            return count
        
# otherwise indicate there is no match
return "No match"

# example of how to call function
print(findnth('C$100$150xx', "$", 2))
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts. That's especially important when there's already an accepted answer that's been validated by the community. Under what conditions might your approach be preferred? Are you taking advantage of new capabilities?

Answer (score -3):

How about:

```
c = os.getcwd().split('\\')
print '\\'.join(c[0:-2])
```

Comment: this is not an answer to initial question

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).