# Replace only the ending of a string

Tags: python, string, list

It irks me not to be able to do the following in a single line. I've a feeling that it can be done through list comprehension, but how?

```
given_string = "first.second.third.None"
string_splitted = given_string.split('.')
string_splitted[-1] = "fourth"
given_string = ".".join(string_splitted)
```

Please note that the number of dots (.) in the given_string is constant (3). So i always want to replace the fourth fragment of the string.

Comment: so your output is `first.second.third` ?

Comment: No, its 'first.second.third.fourth'

Comment: You *can* do this in one line, but it's not pretty. What's wrong with what you have there? Putting that in a function would be a better approach than a comprehension.

Comment: I'm doing a very simple thing in 3 lines and i've a feeling it can be reduced.

Comment: `".".join("first.second.third.None".split(".")[0:3] + ["fourth"])`

Comment: `re.sub("\.[^\.]*$",".other_thing",original_string)`

Comment: @JoranBeasley i only want the replacement to happen at the end of the string. Your suggestion would replace it anywhere.

Comment: nope ... only from the last period https://repl.it/repls/RunnyIntentProspect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
given_string = "first.second.third.None"
given_string = ".".join(given_string.split('.')[:-1] + ["fourth"])
print(given_string)
```

Output:

```
first.second.third.fourth
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you should be able to do this without splitting into  an array. Find the last `.` and slice to there:

```
> given_string = "first.second.third.None"
> given_string[:given_string.rfind('.')] + '.fourth'

'first.second.third.fourth'
```

Comment: beat me to it!!

Comment: Only 30 seconds @ParitoshSingh!

Comment: I wonder which one is more readable between this and the one Vasilis G. suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one liner:-

```
print (".".join(given_string.split(".")[:-1]+["Fourth"]))
```

Output:

```
first.second.third.Fourth
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use rsplit. This would work no matter how many dots precede the last split

```
given_string = "first.second.third.None"
string_splitted = given_string.rsplit('.', 1)[0] + '.fourth'

print(string_splitted)
first.second.third.fourth
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_string = "first.second.third.None"
my_sub = re.sub(r'((\w+\.){3})(\w+)', r'\1fourth', my_string)
print(my_sub)
first.second.third.fourth
```

A good explanation of this style is here: [How to find and replace nth occurence of word in a sentence using python regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589325/how-to-find-and-replace-nth-occurence-of-word-in-a-sentence-using-python-regular)