# How to replace a specific regex group using re.sub with custom text?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have the following text:

> 'The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN was unaffected by these events.'

I'm trying to replace each word with user input. I am using regular expressions to match the words and get them to a list.

I am using `re.sub` to replace the `userinput` with the matched regex group. But is there a way I can only replace the first matched group, or second or third?

`NOUN` comes up twice, so in my `for` loop, I want the user input to only replace `regex.group[0]` or `[1]`, for example.

Comment: Could you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Tried various things, the re.sub method with count. (this only replaces strings including and up to a value - when i need only a specific value replaces).

Tried the \1 method in re.sub (don't fully understand it) but I think that uses the groups found as part of the replacement pattern in the string.

Answer (score 0):

**edit**
You probably will have to iterate over all words, and make a call for each one, whether you want to change it or not.
I'm not sure, how you want to treat punctuation, but I guess something along this lines should do:

(It iterates over all maximum-characters literals, which don't contain space in them)

```py
import re

x='The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN was unaffected by these events.'
y=''
for wrd in re.findall(r"[^ ]+", x):
    z=input(f"found word {wrd}, replace: ")
    if(z!=''):
        y+=f"{z} "
    else:
        y+=f"{wrd} "

print(y)
```

Ref:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: Right, with this method I know the count goes 'up to count' replacements. But what happens if I just want to replace the third group match, without the other 2 being effected?

Comment: Then you will have to just iterate over it one by one, and put old, or replaced value in a buffer. Check my edit

Comment: Ok I see your code, a think I understand it. But there's no way where you can easily replace a specific regex group by using index and targeting only that group (without count, including all the previous ones).

Comment: I thought so, just googled it though, and there's something: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27589356/11610186 nevertheless if I understand your premise correctly- I would still go with breaking it down to words/literals/bits, and then modifying these one by one, making a call what to do with each one based on user input.

Comment: That helped a lot! Thanks so much man. This might sound stupid, but what did you do to get that search result. I spent an hour  searching various terms (on google) and couldn't find that thread? 

I know most of coding is searching for problems like I have and trying to find the answer so just want to help on that part.

Thanks again!

Comment: :) "how to find regex replace specific occurence python"  on duckduckgo.com to be specific;) I don't do Google to be honest, I just used it as a phrase;)