# To replace the 2nd occurrence of a string element in list

Tags: python, list, replace

A list below and I want to replace the 2nd occurrence of the 'pen' with 'his' in the list:

```
the_list = ['pen has pen cap', 'pen has pen ink', 'pen has pen attitude']
```

referencing [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-find-and-replace-the-second-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string-using-Python):

```
def replace_second(string, a, b):
   return string.replace(a, b, 2).replace(b, a, 1)        # replace the 2nd occurrence 
   #return string.replace(b, a, 2).replace(a, b, 1)       # replace the 1st occurrence

new_list = [replace_second(t, 'pen', 'his') for t in the_list]
```

Output:

```
['pen has his cap', 'pen has his ink', 'pen has his attitude']
```

What would be a better/quicker way? Thank you.

And, inspired by @Keyur Potdar and @AMC, another way could be:

```
n = 2

for t in the_list:
    print (t.replace('pen','$$$',n-1).replace('pen','his',1).replace('$$$','pen'))

# pen has his cap
# pen has his ink
# pen has his attitude
```

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589325/how-to-find-and-replace-nth-occurrence-of-word-in-a-sentence-using-python-regula).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find and replace nth occurrence of word in a sentence using python regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589325/how-to-find-and-replace-nth-occurrence-of-word-in-a-sentence-using-python-regula)

Comment: @Keyur Potdar, thank you! love the 1-liner!

Comment: @AMC, thank you! it's the same link as Keyur Potdar pointed.