nth substring multiplicity using itertools
I am trying to write a function that returns a string with the nth substring replaced by a new substring.
I tried the following:
import re
from itertools import count

text = "Hello_Dear_Today_is_Nice_Today_is_Nice"

def replace_nth(text, sub, rep_sub, n):
    c = count(0)
    res = re.sub(r"{}".format(sub), lambda x: rep_sub if next(c) == n else x.group(), text)
    return res

print(replace_nth(text, "Today", "Today_2", 2))

But the returned string is the same, what am I doing wrong?
I am expecting:
Hello_Dear_Today_is_Nice_Today_2_is_Nice as a  result

Another approach using negative lookahead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589325/how-to-find-and-replace-nth-occurrence-of-word-in-a-sentence-using-python-regula/35091930

An overkill for my problem, but it s a very neat one ;)

What would be the output of replacing the 2nd occurrence of the substring aa with bb in the string aaaa by your definition? Is it abba or aabb?

that s classic, but I intend abba

@WiktorStribiżew No, this is NOT a duplicate of that. They're not asking how to do it, they're asking about what they're doing wrong in their itertools solution attempt. And neither that other question nor any of its answers use itertools at all, let alone are answering this.

Without any deps, certainly a lot faster than re/itertools.
If the string contains the substring n times, the number resulting from the split must be n+1 . If that is not the case, the function returns None
def replace_nth(text, sub, rep_sub, n):
    return (sub.join(g[:n]) + rep_sub + g[n]) if len(g:=text.split(sub,maxsplit=n))==n+1 else None

text = "Hello_Dear_Today_is_Nice_Today_is_Nice"

print(replace_nth(text, "Today", "Today_2", 2))


One approach would be to use re.finditer():
from re import finditer

text = "Hello_Dear_Today_is_Nice_Today_is_Nice"

def replace_nth(text, sub, rep_sub, n):
  m = list(finditer(sub, text))
  try:
    return f"{text[0:m[n].span()[0]]}{rep_sub}{text[m[n].span()[1]:]}"
  except IndexError:
    return text

x = replace_nth(text, "Today", "Today_2", 1)

print(x)

Small error handling done via exception handling will ensure that if nth match ain't found or text doesn't contain sub, original text is returned.

I guess you want to replace it from the back.
If that's the case, you can simply use split():

text = "Hello_Dear_Today_is_Nice_Today_is_Nice"


def replace_nth(text, sub, rep_sub, n):
    s = text.split('_')
    s[-n - 1] = rep_sub
    return '_'.join(s)


print(replace_nth(text, "Today", "Today_2", 2))




Hello_Dear_Today_is_Nice_Today_2_is_Nice


Edit:
It seems that you're trying to match from the left. In that case:
def replace_nth(text, sub, rep_sub, n):
    s = text.split('_')
    for i, word in enumerate(s):
        if word.startswith(sub):
            n -= 1
            if n == 0:
                s[i] = rep_sub
                break
    return '_'.join(s) if n == 0 else 'False inputs'


text = "Hello_Dear_Today_is_Nice_Today_is_Nice"
print(replace_nth(text, "Today", "Today_2", 2))
print(replace_nth(text, "Today", "Today_2", 4))
print(replace_nth(text, "Today", "Today_2", 1))



Hello_Dear_Today_is_Nice_Today_2_is_Nice
False inputs
Hello_Dear_Today_2_is_Nice_Today_is_Nice


It seems to me that the occurrences of _ in the OP's string should not have an impact on the problem; the problem is to search for substring sub in string text, without splitting text into words.

@Stef You're most likely right. When I answered, the question was not fully clear to me. Was gusseing. Thanks for the comment.

@Stef Exactly!!

You can build a regex that matches n - 1 occurrences of sub before matching the n-th occurrence of sub:
def replace_nth(text, sub, rep_sub, n):
    if n > 1:
        sub = rf'^(.*?(?:{sub}.*?){{{n - 1}}}){sub}'
        rep_sub = r'\1' + rep_sub
    return re.sub(sub, rep_sub, text, count=1)

Demo: https://ideone.com/XsqgGE

you need to adjust the condition to check for the nth occurrence correctly (1-based index).
import re
from itertools import count
def replace_nth(text, sub, rep_sub, n):
    def replacement(match):
        replacement.counter += 1
        if replacement.counter == n:
            return rep_sub
        else:
            return match.group()
    
    replacement.counter = 0
    res = re.sub(r"{}".format(sub), replacement, text)
    return res

# Test the function
text = "Hello_Dear_Today_is_Nice_Today_is_Nice"
print(replace_nth(text, "Today", "Today_2", 2))

OUTPUT :



what am I doing wrong?

You started counting with 0. Use count(1) instead.

What's the issue? This is 100% the correct answer, and the first one to actually answer the question.
