# python find position of characters in a string ignoring special characters in this string

Tags: string, python-2.7, char

I have a string

```
s1='abcdebcfg'
```

And for some reason the same string with added characters `('-','.')`

```
s2='..abcde--bc-fg'
```

I want to map the index of a character from `s1` to `s2`

Example:`s1:0 -->s2:2 , s1:5 -->s2:9 ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by : 
counting the number of occurrence of the character in `s1` at position `i` and then find the character `s1[i]` in `s2` that has the same number of occurrence

```
def find_nth(needle,haystack, n):
    start = haystack.find(needle)
    while start >= 0 and n > 1:
        start = haystack.find(needle, start+len(needle))
        n -= 1
    return start


for i in range(len(s1)) :
        occurrence= s1[:i+1].count(s1[i])    

        j=find_nth(s1[i], s2, occurrence)
```

Note I found the find_nth [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883980/find-the-nth-occurrence-of-substring-in-a-string)

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
    for i in len(s1):
       j = s2.find(s1[i])
       print "s1:",i,"-->s2:",j
```

Answer (score -1):

you may use two stack for each (s1,s2)with index as key and character as value  then pop the values from each compare them and generate required output.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so something like this should work:

```
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        for j in range (i,len(s2)):
            if s2[j]==s1[i]:
                print "s1:",i,"-->s2:",j
                break
```