# Regex find string after key inside qoutes

Tags: python, regex

Input:

> blalasdl8ujd "key":"value", blblabla asdw
>   "alo":"ebobo",blabla"www":"zzzz"

or

> blalasdl8ujd key ***[any_chars_here]*** "value", blabla asdw
>   "alo":"ebobo", bla"www":"zzzz"

I'm tring to extract `value` having only `key` and knowing that `value` is covered with `"`

Following regex `key.*"(.*?)"` returns the last match covered with " (`"zzzz"`).
I need to fix it to return first.

https://regex101.com/r/CDfhBT/1

Comment: would a python solution that doesn't use regex be acceptable?

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 I guess you are thinking about using dictionaries ;)

Comment: also please specify if there is more than one key possible per string

Comment: `"key"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the non-greedy quantifier `.*?` between the `key` and the value group:

```
key.*?"(.*?)"
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/CDfhBT/4).

#### Update

You might wonder why it captures the colon, `:`. It captures that because this is the next thing between quotes. So you can add optional quotes around `key` like this:

```
("?)key\1.*?"(.*?)"
```

Another demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/CDfhBT/6).

Comment: That won't handle any escaped characters within the value.

Comment: That's right. However, I can't see the definition of an escaped character in the question. Do we escape with double quotes? Or rather with backslashes?

Comment: ("?)key\1.*?"(.*?)"    is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/CDfhBT/7)

```
"key"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"
```

To match the possibility of escaped double quotes you can use the following regex:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/CDfhBT/9)

```
"key"\s*:\s*"((?:(?<!\\)\\(?:\\{2})*"|[^"])*)"
```

This method ensures that an odd number of backslashes `\` precedes the double quotation character `"` such that `\"`, `\\\"`, `\\\\\"`, etc. are valid, but `\\"`, `\\\\"`, `\\\\\\"` are not valid (this would simply output a backslash character, thus the double quotation character `"` preceded by an even number of backslashes would simply result in a string termination).

#### Matching both strings

If you're looking to match your second string as well, you can use either of the following regexes:

```
\bkey\b(?:"\s*:\s*|.*?)"([^"]*)"
\bkey\b(?:"\s*:\s*|.*?)"((?:(?<!\\)\\(?:\\{2})*"|[^"])*)"
```

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/aCwj2h)

```
import re

s = 'blahblah "key":"value","TargetCRS": "Target","TargetCRScode": "vertical Code","zzz": "aaaa" sadzxc "sss"'
r = re.compile(r'''"key"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"''')

match = r.search(s)
if match:
    print match.group(1)
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
blahblah "key":"value","TargetCRS": "Target","TargetCRScode": "vertical Code","zzz": "aaaa" sadzxc "sss"
blalasdl8ujd key [any_chars_here] "value", blabla asdw "alo":"ebobo", bla"www":"zzzz"
```

#### Output

**String 1**

- Match: `"key":"value"`
- Capture group 1: `value`

**String 2** (when using one of the methods under **Matching both strings**)

- Match: `key [any_chars_here] "value"`
- Capture group 1: `value`

---

### Explanation

- `"key"` Match this literally
- `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters
- `:` Match the colon character literally
- `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters
- `"` Match the double quotation character literally
- `([^"]*)` Capture any character not present in the set (any character except the double quotation character `"`) any number of times into capture group 1
- `"` Match the double quotation character literally

#### Matching both strings

- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
- `key` Match this literally
- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
- `(?:"\s*:\s*|.*?)` Match either of the following

  - `"\s*:\s*`

    - `"` Match this literally
    - `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters
    - `:` Match this literally
    - `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters
  - `.*?` Match any character any number of times, but as few as possible
- `"` Match this literally
- `([^"]*)` Capture any number of any character except `"` into capture group 1
- `"` Match this literally

Comment: The double quotes inside a string defined with double quotes isn't working for you... use single quotes to define to regex and then you can use double quotes inside.

Comment: @JoeIddon what? This outputs what the OP is asking for no?

Comment: You can't define a string in python that contains double quotes `"` with double quotes. So `s = "hello "bob"."` is in valid

Comment: @JoeIddon I know that, but my answer is in regex, the OP has to escape the double quotes or click the "Code Generator" button on regex101.

Comment: @JoeIddon I added usage above.

Comment: Actually the purpose was to make regex that will match value from both of inputs. Anyway, thanks for your explanations.

Comment: @PATAPOsha at the end of my **Code** section I've added a **Matching both strings** section, which contains two regular expressions that match both the first and second strings. I also added an explanation for one such method in the **Explanation** section. These methods existed in my answer before, I simply made it more apparent and added the explanation. P.S. the chosen answer does work, but fails against escaped double quotes `"` and also matches `key` when it could be part of another word. For example, change `key` to `rekey`. You'll see it matches, whereas mine does not.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
.*(\"key\":\"(\w*)\")
```

Using the group 2:

https://regex101.com/r/66ikH3/2

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a somewhat more pythonic way to do this, but:

```
s1 = 'blalasdl8ujd "key":"value", blblabla asdw "alo":"ebobo",blabla"www":"zzzz"'
s2 = 'blalasdl8ujd key [any_chars_here] "value", blabla asdw "alo":"ebobo", bla"www":"zzzz"'


def getValue(string, keyName = 'key'):
    """Find next quoted value after a key that may or may not be quoted"""
    startKey = string.find(keyName) 
    # if key is quoted, adjust value search range to exclude its closing quote
    endKey = string.find('"',startKey) if string[startKey-1]=='"' else startKey + len(keyName) 
    startValue = string.find('"',endKey+1)+1
    return string[startValue:string.find('"',startValue+1)]

getValue(s1) #'value'
getValue(s2) #'value'
```

I was inspired by the elegance of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13094326/2573061), but handling the quoted and unquoted cases makes it more than a 1-liner.

You can use a comprehension such as:

```
next(y[1][1:-1] for y in [[l for l in x.split(':')] 
     for  x in s2.split(',')] if 'key' in y[0]) # returns 'value' w/o quotes
```

But that won't handle the case of `s2`.