# Returning the part of a string that is found before the first blank line in the string in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have a string that has allot of blank lines, I need to return the chunk of that string that is found before the first blank line in it.
For Example:

```
aaaaa
bbbb
1223

212
fff
```

The returned string should be:

```
aaaaa
bbbb
1223
```

Note: I am using Python 2.7

Comment: [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on `\n\n` or whatever the line separator character is **doubled** and get the 0-index element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def find(string):
    return string[:string.find('\n\n')]
```

Comment: check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883980/find-the-nth-occurrence-of-substring-in-a-string)

You could also just try something like: `return string[1:string.find('\n\n')]`

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach. Using a simple iteration.

**Demo:**

```
res = []
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if not line.strip():
            break
        else:
            res.append(line)
print( "".join(res) )
```

Comment: why `" ".join` and not `"".join`?