# How to find the index of the nth ocurrence of a character in a string

Tags: python-3.x, string

```
"/home/hernan/PycharmProjects/test1/tensor.py".find('e')   #Returns 4
"/home/hernan/PycharmProjects/test1/tensor.py".find('e',2) #Also 4
"/home/hernan/PycharmProjects/test1/tensor.py".find('e',3) #Also 4
```

**I would like something like:**

```
"/home/hernan/PycharmProjects/test1/tensor.py".find('e',2) #Returns 7
"/home/hernan/PycharmProjects/test1/tensor.py".find('e',3) #Returns 14
```

Those are the **second** and **third** ocurrences of **'e'**.

### Any built-in function in Python 3.x to get the index of the *nth* ocurrence of a character in a string?

Comment: Why not use for-loop?

Comment: i Could do that, but Im looking for a built-in function in Python. I've specified my answer so that it is clearer.

Comment: I see. There's a very comprehensive question and answers on Stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883980/find-the-nth-occurrence-of-substring-in-a-string). However I don't believe there's any built-in function that can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a for-loop?

```
def find_nth(text, sub, nth):
    start = -1
    for i in range(nth):
        start = text.find(sub, start + 1)
        if start == -1:
            break
    return start


find_nth("/home/hernan/PycharmProjects/test1/tensor.py", 'e', 2) # returns 7
find_nth("/home/hernan/PycharmProjects/test1/tensor.py", 'e', 3) # returns 24
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument in the `str.find` function is to indicate the start index. Not the index of the occurrence to start looking from. `'find a char'.find('a', 3)` is equivalent to `'find a char'[3:].find('a') + 3` (sort of; not dealing with the search string not being present in the full string that it's being searched for in). You'll have to write your own function for this.

```
def search(full, toFind, occ):
    ret = 0
    while occ:
        ret = full.find( toFind, ret ) + 1
        occ -= 0
        if ret == -1:
            return -1
    return ret
```