# Finding nth position of substring in a string using python

Tags: python, string, substring

Let's take example string, 'I am programmer and I am doing coding. I am interested in it' and the target word (substring) is 'am'. I want to find nth value of it where it is located by the complete words, not indexes. For example, substring 'am' is located on 2nd, 6th and 10 position.
I tried searching but all the results were relevant to finding indexes. One I found about nth value didn't work for me. Code was giving error on ':' of 'IF'.

```
    parts= haystack.split(needle, n+1)
    if len(parts)<=n+1:
        return -1
    return len(haystack)-len(parts[-1])-len(needle)
```

Do you have an optimum and simple solution for this. I am trying to just solve the problem with possible solutions and logics. Your cooperation will be well appreciated.

Comment: So you only want to match entire words, is that correct?  Otherwise "programmer" would match "am".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all occurrences of an element in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list) (where the list is the result of `haystack.split(" ")`)

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes. In short I wanna find the whole word with it's position according to words on nth position.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the nth occurrence of substring in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883980/find-the-nth-occurrence-of-substring-in-a-string)

Comment: @SuperStormer I tried with following code using the link you shared.
```#!/bin/python3
def FindNthTargetString(string, target):
 counter=0
 lst=[]
 if target in string:
  li=list(string.split(" "))
  j = [i for i, x in enumerate(li) if x == target]
  print("Positions of string ",target," is :-")
  for s in range(len(j)):
   print(j[s]+1)


 else:
  return "Target word not in the string."



It worked well with this string, not for "Today is my sessional exam. I am not fully prepared for exam. I don't know, how I will perform in exam"

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
string = 'I am programmer and I am doing coding. I am interested in it'.split()
target = 'am'
for count,words in enumerate(string):
    if words == target:
        print(count)
```

This will give you `1,5,9`. This is because indexes start from zero. Now ofcourse if you want 2,6,10 you can just add one to count whenever it is printed.

**list comprehension**

```
string = 'I am programmer and I am doing coding. I am interested in it'.split()
target = 'am'
wordPlace = [count for count,words in enumerate(string) if words == target]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The code above, it returned me **22** with the string **Today is my sessional exam. I am not fully prepared for exam. I don't know, how I will perform in exam** and finding target word **exam**. The desired output is 4, 11 and 20 on this string mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I tried following code and it worked on the string below where the function is called.

```
    counter=0
    lst=[]
    if target in string:
        li=list(string.split(" ")) #li is list, string to list
        j = [i for i, x in enumerate(li) if x == "exam"]
        print("Positions of string ",target," is :-")
        for s in range(len(j)):
            print(j[s]+1)


    else:
        return "Target word not in the string."

print(findTargetWord("Today is my exam and exam is easy", "exam")) #it worked on this string
```

I tried string **Today is my sessional exam. I am not fully prepared for exam. I don't know, how I will perform in exam**.
Instead of returning me the correct answer, it print **21**.