# Python Dataframe find the index of a second occurance of a string

Tags: python, string, substring

I have seen that similar questions have been psoted, but the solutions there do not work for me because, I believe, I am working with a column in a dataframe.

I have a column which has a string in it.  I find the first occurance of a term.  This works.  I then want to find the second occurance of that term.  This doesn't work.

My code

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"Text" : ["['one', 'one two']","['two one', 'three']"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#yes the data is in a list in a column but I treat it as a string

#finding if "one" is in the string - works
df["Ones"] = df.Text.str.find("one")
#finding if "one" is in the string another time as in the first row
df["NextOnes"] = df.Text.str.find("one",df.Ones +1)
```

The line for "NextOnes" returns NAs.  In my real code, it returns blanks.  If I replace the reference to the column with a number, such as 2, then this returns the correct value.  However this value needs to be dynamic.

I have just got this the needle haystack approach to work but building in for loops seems inefficient [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883980/find-the-nth-occurrence-of-substring-in-a-string),

```
 for i in range(len(df)):
...     df["Next"][i] = find_nth(str(df.Text[i]),"one",2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the find method from str, but pass in the previous item index as starting point (as parameter to find).

Comment: Sadly I already tried this and it didn't work.  Covered in the original post.
df["NextOnes"] = df.Text.str.find("one",df.Ones +1)
Or do you mean something different?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Unfortunately, I got no better idea. Your "slow" solution seems good though.