# How to insert a string after a specific closing curly brace in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to insert a sub string right after a specific closing curly brace of a string.

For example let's say the full string looks like following:

```
"{records#QUERY# { edges { node { id legalname countryiso naicscode naicsdescription } } <need to place another string here> } }"
```

So I'd need to like append a string in that place holder `<>` above (please note that in the original string this place holder won't be provided).

Basically I need to find out the closing curly brace of the second opening curly brace and place it before that.

Any help or pointers could be appreciated.

Comment: maybe look at this question, it is fairly similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883980/find-the-nth-occurrence-of-substring-in-a-string - here it would get you the position of the character and then use this to insert the string https://www.adamsmith.haus/python/answers/how-to-insert-a-character-into-a-string-at-an-index-in-python

Comment: Double curly brackets? `"{{records#QUERY# {{ edges {{ xx }} }} {} }}".format('xxx')`?

Comment: thnx @r.user.05apr Unfortunately we can't change that query.. since its coming from a metadata service..plus it doesn't come with a place holder in the original string. I need to find and append it

Answer (score 1):

Hi| Is the end always the same ? "}} }}" if so you can remove it and add it witht he new text.

```
text = "{records#QUERY# { edges { node { id legalname countryiso naicscode naicsdescription } } } }"
text_split = ss.strip("} }")

new_text2 = text_split+("} } New Text Inserted } }")
```

Comment: thnx @dini.. yeah the end will be always the same.. but i have one question in the above approach.. how will it know to strip the last two curly braces and not the ones before that?

Comment: It will remove the last 4 because we said }} and they appear twice and then we add {{ text }}

Answer (score 1):

Dini's answer is practical, but if you want to use regex for this purpose, one solution may be:

```
import re
string = "{records#QUERY# { edges { node { id legalname countryiso naicscode naicsdescription } } <need to place another string here> } }"
match = re.search("\{.*?\{.*?\{.*?\{.*?\}.*?(\}).*?(\}).*?\}",string)

idx1 = match.span(1)[0] # index of second "}"
idx2 = match.span(2)[0] # index of third "}"

string = string[:idx1+1] + " " + "apple" + " " + string[idx2:]
print(string)
```

Output is:

```
{records#QUERY# { edges { node { id legalname countryiso naicscode naicsdescription } } apple } }
```

Comment: Regex will be a better solution, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by finding the indices of the second close curly brace from last and the third and placed the string in between them:

```
fetcher_query = "{records#QUERY# { edges { node { id legalname countryiso naicscode naicsdescription}}}}"
    
close_curly_brace_iterator = re.finditer(r"}", fetcher_query)
indices = [m.start(0) for m in close_curly_brace_iterator]

third_before_last_idx = indices[-2]  # index of third from last }
second_before_last_idx = indices[-3]  # index of second from last }

fetcher_query = fetcher_query[:third_before_last_idx] + " " + "pageInfo {endCursor hasNextPage}" + " " + fetcher_query[second_before_last_idx:-1]
logger.info(f'updated fetcher query with graphql pagination: {fetcher_query}')
```